# R: Print A Value from A Column Based on the Corresponding Row of Another Column

Tags: r

I have this data frame `df` in `R` in which I want to print (as a scalar) a value of column `Y` based on the corresponding row that is the minimum value of column `Z`. For example, since `1.928718` is the minimum in column `Z` I will pick the corresponding row value in column `Y` which is `5`.

```
df <- read.table(text = 
      "X Y Z
      a  2 3.258206
      b  6 2.825460
      c  5 1.928718
      d  3 3.656937
      e  3 2.060350",
      header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Try `df$Y[df$Z == min(df$Z)]`

Comment: You could use `df$Y[which.min(df$Z)]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `slice_min`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 slice_min(Z) %>%
 pull(Y)
[1] 5
```